# Haskell - Type conversion?

Tags: haskell, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert data from a list, 'profile1', into a custom type called 'DataSubject'.

I'm passing this to a function 'makeDS' to attempt this conversion - however the following isn't working:

```
type Name = String 
type Age = Int 
type Iq = Int
type Language = String 
data DataSubject = DS {name :: Name, age :: Age, iq :: Iq, language :: Language} deriving (Show)
data Contain = Name String | Age Int | Iq Int | Language String deriving (Show) --Use so list can take multiple types

profile1 = [Name "Bob", Age 22, Iq 100, Language "French"]

makeDS :: [Contain] -> DataSubject
makeDS t = DS {name = t!!0, age = t!!1, iq = t!!2, language = t!!3}

main = do
  let x = makeDS profile1
  putStrLn $ show x
```

Error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Contain’ with ‘[Char]’
```

I'm just getting started with Haskell - could someone advise on my error? And if there's better ways of doing this?

Comment: What is the purpose of such a function? Anything that can produce a `[Contain]` can just as easily create a `DataSubject` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the definition of `makeDS`, the variable `t` is of type `[Contain]` (i.e. a list of `Contain`), so when you say `t!!0` this will extract the first element of that list, which has type `Contain`. The problem is that the `name` field of `DataSubject` contains a `String` (which is an alias of `[Char]`). So you are trying to store a `Contain` in the place of `[Char]`, which is not possible because the types are different. You need a different approach in you code.

One issue is that every single `Contain` value represents a single field of `DataSubject`. So if we are given a list of `Contain`, there is no guarantee that the values will be given in a specific order (e.g. `Name` first, followed by `Age`, etc) or even that all fields are provided. Even if you always provide all fields in a specific order in your code as convention, haskell cannot possibly know that. One solution that does not depend on order is to try to "build" the `DataSubject` object step-by-step, by starting with an "empty" `DataSubject` and then examining the list of `Contain` and adding the corresponding `DataSubject` field:

```
makeDS :: [Contain] -> DataSubject
makeDS = foldr updateDS emptyDS
  where
    updateDS (Name s) ds = ds {name = s}
    updateDS (Age n) ds = ds {age = n}
    updateDS (Iq n) ds = ds {iq = n}
    updateDS (Language s) ds = ds {language = s}
    emptyDS = DS {name = "", age = 0, iq = 0, language = ""}
```

So here, I defined `emptyDS` which is an "empty" `DataSubject` object and a function called `updateDS` which take a (single) `Contain` and a `DataSubject` and updates the `DataSubject` based on the field specified by `Contain` and then it returns it. Finally, I use a fold to run repeatedly update the `DataSubject` (starting with `emptyDS`) using `updateDS`.

Comment: could you add a brief explanation of your code and exactly what its doing, then I can accept answer

Comment: I've updated my answer with a brief explanation of how the fold works.

Answer (score 3):

You have a **type mismatch**. You have a list of `Contain`. So when you use

```
t !! 0
```

you get a `Contain`, not a `String`, which is necessary for `name` in `DS`. You need a function `Contain -> Name`, e.g.

```
containToName :: Contain -> Name
containToName (Name xs) = xs
containToName _         = error "not a name"
```

However, that's a partial function, since `containToName (Age 12)` will lead to an error.

Note that this has nothing to do with *typeclasses*. Now, if you want to use `profile1`, one way would be to just use

```
profile1 :: DataSubject
```

instead of

```
profile1 :: [Contain]
```

e.g.

```
profile1 :: DataSubject 
profile1 = DS "Bob" 22 100 "French"
```

After all, there's nothing in the *type* `[Contain]` that will make sure that you have all the ingredients for a complete `DataSubject`.

> And if there's better ways of doing this?

That depends on what you want to do. If you just want to handle `DataSubject`s, don't use an temporary list of `Contain`. If you want to handle user input (or similar), it gets a little bit more tricky.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of `DataSubject` says that we need a `Name` for the `name` field. And `Name` is the same as `String`. So in the expression `DS {name = t!!0, ...}`, we need `t !! 0` to return a `String`. However, `t !! 0` returns an element of  `t`, and `t` has type `[Contain]`. So `t !! 0` has type `Contain`, which is different from `String`.

To fix this type error, you need to convert the `Contain` to a `String`, maybe so:

```
DS { name = case t !! 0 of Name s => s, ... }
```